# Insert data from HTML form into Kendo grid data

Tags: javascript, php, html, kendo-grid

I have tried to select the data in dropdown then submit into kendo grid. But, the data failed to be insert into grid. Anyone have idea or solution?

> HTML submit button

```
<button class="k-button" id="btnSave" value="submit" style="float:right; padding: 5px 20px; border-radius: 4px;" >Submit</button>
```

> JavaScript button submit

```
    //AJAX call for button
    $("#btnSave").kendoButton();
    var button = $("#btnSave").data("kendoButton");
    button.bind("click", function(e) {

    var test = $("#accountLedger").val()

    $.ajax({
        url: "../GroupManagement/get.php",
        type: "POST",
            data: {
                method: "addGroup",
                accountLedgerID: $("#accountLedgerID").val()

                },
                success: function () {                
                kendo.alert ('success');
```

> JavaScript dropdown

```
        $("#accountLedger").kendoDropDownList({
        dataTextField: "accountLedgerName",
        dataValueField: "accountLedgerID",
        optionLabel: "Choose account ledger",
        dataSource: {
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url:  "./getCoaGroup.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: function() {
                            return { 
                                method: "getAccLedger",
                        }
                    }
                },
            },
        },
        //change: onChange(),
        change: function(e){
            console.log(this.value());
            $('#grid').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
            homogeneous.read();
        }
    }).data('kendoDropDownList');

    dropdownlist = $("#accountLedger").data("kendoDropDownList");
```

> JavaScript Kendo Grid

```
columns: [
            columns: [
                { field: "active", title:" ", filterable:false,
                template: "# if( data.active == 'y' ){# <span class='k-icon ehors-status-active-icon'></span> #} else {# <span class='k-icon ehors-status-inactive-icon'></span> #} #" },
                { field: "accountLedgerID", title:"Ledger Name", editor: getLedger, 
                template:" #= (data.accountLedgerID) ? kendo.toString (data.accountLedgerName): '' #" }]
```

> PHP Insert

```
   /* ADD */
 function addGroup() {
global $ehorsObj;
$accountID  = (isset($_POST['accountID']) ? $_POST['accountID'] : '');
$accountLedgerID   = (isset($_POST['accountLedgerID']) ? $_POST['accountLedgerID'] : '');

/ check unique /
$sqlCount   =   "SELECT COUNT AS TOTAL FROM tblAccAccounts
                 WHERE accountID != '" . $accountID . "'
                 AND accountLedgerID = '" . $accountLedgerID . "'
                 ";
$GetResult = $ehorsObj->FetchData($sqlCount, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);
while ($row = $GetResult->fetch()){
    $total = $row ['TOTAL'];
}
if ($total == 0){

    $accountID = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK(tblAccAccounts);
    $sqlAdd     =   "INSERT INTO tblAccAccounts
                    SET accountID = '" . $accountID . "',
                    accountLedgerID = '" . $accountLedgerID . "',                       
                    dateTimeEmployee = NOW() ";     

    $ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAdd, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);        

    $accountLog = $ehorsObj->EHORS_PK(tblAccAccountsLog);
    $sqlAddLog  =   "INSERT INTO tblAccAccountsLog
                    SET accountLog = '" . $accountLog . "',
                    accountID = '" . $accountID . "',
                    accountLedgerID = '" . $accountLedgerID . "',
                    dateTimeEmployee = NOW(),
                    active = 'y' ";
$ehorsObj->ExecuteData($sqlAddLog, $ehorsObj->DEFAULT_PDO_CONNECTIONS);  
}else{
    echo "Record already exist";
}}
```

This is my output [image]

If you see the picture, the grid above column ledger name do not have the data. Its suppose the user select the dropdown then click submit. After that, selected data in dropdown will be insert into grid. Hope anyone can give any  reference about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There should be `: {` in your code after 'transport' and 'read'.

Below this part of code fixed:

```
dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {
                url:  "./getCoaGroup.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: function() {
                        return { 
                            method: "getAccLedger",
                    }
                }
            },
        },
```

Comment: I have put it, but nothing happened too

Answer (score 0):

I not sure either it works or not but have you try to change the `accountLedgerID` to other name. I had the same problem as well, it maybe because of confusion regarding the variable name.

*JavaScript button submit*

```
accLedgerID: $("#accountLedgerID").val()
```

*PHP*

```
$accLedgerID= (isset($_POST['accLedgerID']) ? $_POST['accLedgerID'] : '');
```